inverse function in qiskit not generating inverted circuits
I am struggling with the inverse function of qiskit.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiPF2SVb7xc
The inverse function works for the example shown in the video but it is not working for the circuit I am testing it below as shown:
qc = QuantumCircuit(5)
for i in range(2):
    qc.h(i+1)
    
for i in range(2):
    qc.swap(i+1, i+2+1)
    
for i in range(2):
    qc.h(i+1)

qc.draw(output='mpl')


qc.inverse()
qc.draw(output='mpl')


It would be really great help if someone can explain me what I am doing wrong.

qc.inverse() is not an in-place function; instead, it returns a new QuantumCircuit object. Replace your code with:
qc_inv = qc.inverse()
qc_inv.draw(output='mpl')


Thank you @diemilio for great help.
